# How to put section/subsection heading side by side in beamer template

Tags: beamer

For now I'm using

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
    {%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
      \end{beamercolorbox}
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
          leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
        \insertsectionhead
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
      \end{beamercolorbox}
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2ex,dp=1.125ex,%
        leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=blue}%
        \footnotesize\insertsubsectionhead
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
      \end{beamercolorbox}
    }
```

above code to put section/subsection heading with Darmstadt theme.

What I want is to put section/subsection heading side by side.

How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: A sketch of the expected output would be really helpful here, as there are many possible ways to place section and subsection headings side by side. Would you mind adding one to your question?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the headline template defined by the `infolines` outer theme (file name: beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty). Probably this one already suits your needs.

Comment: @leandriis I added a screenshot. Thanks for noting me that.

Comment: Do you like the header of the `infolines` outer theme? To try, add `\usetheme{infolines}` to the preamble of your document?

Comment: @leandriis \usetheme{infolines} failed with an error saying 'beamerthemeinfolines.sty not found' but I googled it and found answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in my previous commen.t `\useoutertheme{infolines}` should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you reduce the width of the `beamercolorbox`s, you can fit them besides each other:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
    {%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
      \end{beamercolorbox}
      \hbox{%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
          leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil,wd=.5\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
        \insertsectionhead
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
        leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil,wd=.5\paperwidth]{subsection in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=blue}%
        \insertsubsectionhead
      \end{beamercolorbox}}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
      \end{beamercolorbox}
    }
\makeatother

\title{title}

\begin{document}
    
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}  
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frametitle}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```